# Newsletter checkbox at WP shop checkout

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

How can a newsletter checkbox be handled at checkout and the relevant contents be transmitted to CiviCRM? My customer is a Drupal 7 based CiviCRM at 5.47.4 with a separate WP website.  Newsletter signup used to go to a WP based system but is now working OK through a webform into Civi.  Also, however, users can purchase items from the WP website through (I think) Woohoo, and previously just ticked a box at shop checkout.  How can this be transmitted to Civi?  They've already entered their name and email address during the shop checkout process, so it's "just" a question of transmitting that information to Civi as a newsletter signup.  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT - this answers the question as I understood it when first posted - it does not answer the request for passing info from a remote Woohoo form.]

Checkout isn't a civicrm term. if you mean eg a Donation/Membership page (Contribution page in civi parlance) then there are a few ways you can do this

1/ add a custom field, then add it to your profile on the form, then make a Smart Group based on that field

2/ set up a Group to be 'public' then add the Group field to your profile. This will cause all 'public' groups to be listed, so would only suit your use case if you only have the one public group.

Comment: Thanks, Pete, my question wasn't clear enough so I've updated it.  Users have a Woohoo shop, and there's a newsletter tickbox at the shop checkout

Comment: ok. sorry no idea. i edited my Answer to make it clear it doesn't now answer your question :-)